# attempt to de-reference null object rest class

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, rest, httprequest

While performing a POST via workbench i am getting `attempt to de-reference null object` error in line no 32.

I am not getting where i am doing wrong -

Rest Class -

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Order/*')
global with sharing class OrderWebServices {

    private class OrderWrapper {
        Account account;
        list<ContactWrapper> contacts;
    }

    private class ContactWrapper {
        Contact contact;
        Opportunity opp;
        list<Subscription_Offer__c> customers;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost() {

        OrderWrapper container = (OrderWrapper)System.JSON.deserialize(
            RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring(), 
            OrderWrapper.class);

        Account acc = container.account;
        insert acc;

        list<Contact> contactsToInsert = new list <Contact>();

        list<Opportunity> oppToInsert = new list <Opportunity>();

        for (ContactWrapper wcon :container.contacts) {
            wcon.contact.accountId = acc.id;
            system.debug('@@@@@' + acc.id);
            wcon.opp.accountId = acc.id;
            contactsToInsert.add(wcon.contact);
            oppToInsert.add(wcon.opp);
        }
        insert contactsToInsert;
        insert oppToInsert;

        //now wrapper list contains contact ids
        list<Subscription_Offer__c> customersToInsert = new list <Subscription_Offer__c>();
        for (ContactWrapper wcon :container.contacts) {
            for (Subscription_Offer__c customer :wcon.customers) {
                customer.Bill_To__c = wcon.contact.id;
                customer.Opportunity__c = wcon.opp.id;
                customersToInsert.add(customer);
            }
        }
        insert customersToInsert;
        return acc.id;
    }
}
```

Json -

```
    {
    "account": {
        "name": "Wonderland1"
    },
    "contacts": [{
        "contact": {
            "LastName": "Alice1",
            "Email": "Alice1@test.com"
        },
        "opp": {
            "Name": "Aliceopp",
            "CloseDate": "8/8/2017",
            "StageName": "Qualification"
        },
        "customers": [{
            "Name": "Mad Hatter1"
        }, {
            "Name": "Cheshire Cat1"
        }]
    }, {
        "contact": {
            "LastName": "Queen1",
            "Email": "Queen1@test.com"
        },
        "customers": [{
            "Name": "King1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Did you get acc.Id ?

Comment: So which line is 32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason your getting **attempt to de-reference null object** exception, There no **Opportunity** object has created for **second object**.
and your going assign a **acc.id** to an null object in below code.

> ```
> wcon.opp.accountId = acc.id;
> ```

if you add a system.debug in apex

> ```
> for (ContactWrapper wcon :container.contacts) {
>             system.debug(' wcon ' + wcon);
> ```

You can clearly observe in debug log, for **Opportunity** object is null inside **ContactWrapper**;

Change below json file for second object by **adding additional Opportunity empty object** and the code will run properly .

```
  {
    "account": {
        "name": "Wonderland1"
    },
    "contacts": [{
        "contact": {
            "LastName": "Alice1",
            "Email": "Alice1@test.com"
        },
        "opp": {
            "Name": "Aliceopp",
            "CloseDate": "8/8/2017",
            "StageName": "Qualification"
        },
        "customers": [{
            "Name": "Mad Hatter1"
        }, {
            "Name": "Cheshire Cat1"
        }]
    }, {
        "contact": {
            "LastName": "Queen1",
            "Email": "Queen1@test.com"
        },
        "opp": {
        },
        "customers": [{
            "Name": "King1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

**Or**

Validate the object before your assign **acc.id** to an **wcon.opp.accountId**. 
You can do something like this ,

```
for (ContactWrapper wcon :container.contacts) {
            system.debug(' wcon ' + wcon);
            wcon.contact.accountId = acc.id;
            system.debug('@@@@@' + acc.id);
            if(wcon.opp != null){
            wcon.opp.accountId = acc.id;           
            oppToInsert.add(wcon.opp);
            }
            if(wcon.contact != null)
                contactsToInsert.add(wcon.contact);                
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second object:

```
{
    "contact": {
        "LastName": "Queen1",
        "Email": "Queen1@test.com"
    },
    "customers": [{
        "Name": "King1"
    }
}
```

does not include data for the `opp` field so this like of code:

```
wcon.opp.accountId = acc.id;
```

will generate an NPE because the value `wcon.opp` will be null.

Add null value guards in the code (assuming that the missing data case is valid).